# Insert into table requires specific condition from another table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, constraints

I have two SQL tables with the following schema:

- `road_test` (test_ID, examiner_ID, student_ID, vin, test_date)
- `lessons_count` (student_ID, lessons_taken)

I am looking for some way to require a student to have at least 5 `lessons_taken` before they can insert into the `road_test` table.

Is there some sort of trigger or constraint that allows for this?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include your current attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store count of lessons; calculate it whenever needed.

Here's what I'd suggest:

```
SQL> -- the final table
SQL> create table road_test
  2    (test_id number, student_id number, vin number);

Table created.

SQL> -- table that shows which lessons were taken by which student
SQL> create table lesson
  2    (student_id number, lesson_id number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Trigger which is supposed to control whether you're allowed to insert student's record into the `road_test` table: count number of lessons taken and raise an error if it is too low (I set it to 3 for simplicity):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_road
  2    before insert on road_test
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_cnt number;
  6  begin
  7    select count(*)
  8      into l_cnt
  9      from lesson
 10      where student_id = :new.student_id;
 11    if l_cnt < 3 then
 12       raise_application_error(-20001,
 13         'You have to take at least 3 lessons');
 14    end if;
 15  end;
 16  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Testing (as I said: restricted to 3 lessons, for simplicity):

```
SQL> -- initial record
SQL> insert into lesson(student_id, lesson_id) values (1, 100);

1 row created.

SQL> -- can I enter that student into the ROAD_TEST table? Nope
SQL> insert into road_test (test_id, student_id, vin) values (555, 1, 123456);
insert into road_test (test_id, student_id, vin) values (555, 1, 123456)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: You have to take at least 3 lessons
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BI_ROAD", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BI_ROAD'


SQL> -- Let's insert 2 more lessons for the same student
SQL> insert into lesson(student_id, lesson_id) values (1, 200);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into lesson(student_id, lesson_id) values (1, 300);

1 row created.

SQL> -- New attempt for the ROAD_TEST table:
SQL> insert into road_test (test_id, student_id, vin) values (555, 1, 123456);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From lesson;

STUDENT_ID  LESSON_ID
---------- ----------
         1        100
         1        200
         1        300

SQL> select * from road_test;

   TEST_ID STUDENT_ID        VIN
---------- ---------- ----------
       555          1     123456

SQL>
```